# Cast a returned array to appropriate values

Tags: ruby, shoes

I've got the following code snippet which I'm trying to return to Shoes as an array of integers and strings

```
     Shoes.setup do
  gem 'snmp'
end

class SNMPManager 
  require 'snmp'
  include SNMP
  attr_accessor :hostname, :framerate

  def initialize(params = {})
    @hostname = params.fetch(:hostname, 'localhost')
    @framerate = params.fetch(:framerate, 25)

  end

  def getValues
    Manager.open(:host => @hostname, :mib_modules => ["SNMPv2-MIB"]) do |manager|
      poolArray = []
      ifTable = ObjectId.new("1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1")
      manager.walk(ifTable) do |row|
        poolArray.push(row.inspect)
      end
      groups = poolArray.group_by{ |s| s.split(',').first[/\d+$/] }
      @values = groups.map{ |key, ary| ary.map{ |s| s[/value=(\S+)/, 1] } }

    end
  end

  def to_s
    return @values
  end
end



Shoes.app do
  #@hostname = edit_line
  #man =SNMPManager.new(:host => @hostname)
  man = SNMPManager.new
  man.getValues
  puts 'SNMP Space Monitor'
  man.to_s.each {|v|
    @note = para "#{v[1]} \t(Pool: #{v[0]}) \tCapacity: #{v[3].to_i}  \tFree Protons: #{v[2].to_i} \tPercent Free: %#{(v[3].to_f/v[2].to_f*100).round(2)}"
      }
end
```

For some reason Shoes is displaying it like:
[image: Shoes Screengrab]

But if I run the ruby script normally, and output it with puts, it displays correctly, and calculates the response correctly.
I know I'm missing something obvious, but can't see what it is.
I'm trying to cast the array to another array, but that seems to do bugger all.

Comment: The call to setup() causes an error for me: `uninitialized constant Encoding::US_ASCII`.  I asked a question about that on the shoes mailing list, and apparently shoes is pretty much a self contained package, and getting shoes to import other modules is not something that works well.  Also, your to_s() method still doesn't return a string.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
@values = Array(@values)
```

That is a bit odd.  All the Array constructor does is create a copy of @values.  The only reason you would do that is if @values contains a reference to some array that is referenced by another variable, and you don't want that other variable to be able to change @values.  But then why didn't you make a copy when you first assigned the array to @values?

2) Your to_s method does not return a string.

Comment: A better way to achieve 1 is `@values.dup`. 2 could be a problem :) maybe he wants `@values.inspect`

Comment: It keeps returning the same set of data regardless of what I try - I was hoping to try - even inspecting what's there, doesn't return what I expect.

Comment: @Scott, You need to post a complete, simplified example (with the corrections) that anyone can run and get the same results as you.

Comment: `Array(@values)` will turn a non-array into a one element array. It's a common idiom for when your input could be a single thing or an array of things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to use Shoes.

It looks like Shoes is giving you paras containing `array_of_integers_and_strings.to_s`.

Complete code would be super helpful.

Comment: I've added complete code, and will add the sample output
As soon as I change back to console output, I get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by switching from 'red shoes' to 'green shoes'

No other changes required, but here's my current code (which successfully times out when run as a console app. but not as a shoes app - go figure)

```
require 'green_shoes'
gem 'snmp'

class SNMPManager
  require 'snmp'
  include SNMP
  attr_accessor :hostname, :framerate

  def initialize(params = {})
    @hostname = params.fetch(:hostname, 'localhost')
    @framerate = params.fetch(:framerate, 25)

  end

  def getValues
    Manager.open(:host => @hostname) do |manager|
      @poolArray = []
      poolsTable = ObjectId.new("1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1")
      manager.walk(poolsTable) do |row|
        @poolArray.push(row.inspect)
      end
      if @poolArray.empty?
        puts "Manager Down"
        @poolArray = [
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8650, value=8650 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8651, value=8651 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8650, value=QNewsAK (OCTET STRING)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8651, value=QSuite4AK (OCTET STRING)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8650, value=46835255 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8651, value=11041721 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8650, value=8442357 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8651, value=5717570 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8650, value=0 (INTEGER)]',
          '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8651, value=0 (INTEGER)]',
        ]

      else puts "Manager Up"
      end
      groups = @poolArray.group_by{ |s| s.split(',').first[/\d+$/] }
      @values = groups.map{ |key, ary| ary.map{ |s| s[/value=(\S+)/, 1] } }

    end
  end

  def to_s
    return  @values
  end

  protected

end

Shoes.app(:title=>'SNMP Space Monitor') do
  man = SNMPManager.new
  stack do
  every(300) {
      man.getValues
      man.to_s
      man.to_s.each {|v|
       para "#{v[1]} \t(Pool: #{v[0]}) \tCapacity: #{v[2].to_i}  \tFree Protons: #{v[3].to_i} \tPercent Free: #{(v[3].to_f/v[2].to_f*100).round(2)}%"
      }
    }
      end
end
```